# Crear reproductor de video con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, videojs

Estoy intentando crear un reproductor de video solamente usando jquery y me estoy basando en un tutorial que encontré navegando por internet, este es el código usado en el tutorial:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", eventFullScreen);
    document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", eventFullScreen);
    document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", eventFullScreen);
    document.addEventListener("MSFullscreenChange", eventFullScreen);
    
    $("video").on("play", function(){
        $(this).parent().children(".video-controlls").children(".play-pause").children(".play").hide();
        $(this).parent().children(".video-controlls").children(".play-pause").children(".pause").show();
        $(this).parent().children(".big-icon").hide();
        $(this).parent().children(".video-controlls").show();
    });
    
    $("video").on("pause", function(){
        $(this).parent().children(".video-controlls").children(".play-pause").children(".play").show();
        $(this).parent().children(".video-controlls").children(".play-pause").children(".pause").hide();
    });
    
    $("video").on("timeupdate", function(){
        var currentTime = segundosMinutos(this.currentTime);
        
        $(this).parent().children(".video-controlls").children(".time").children().children(".currentTime").text(currentTime);
        
        timeChange($(this).parent(), "timeupdate", null);
    });
    
    $("video").on("loadeddata", function(){
        var videoTime = segundosMinutos(this.duration);
        
        $(this).parent().children(".video-controlls").children(".time").children().children(".duration").text(videoTime);
    });
    
    $("video").on("ended", function(){
        $(this).parent().children(".big-icon").children().children().children().children().children().attr("class", "fa fa-redo");
        $(this).parent().children(".big-icon").show();
    });
    
    $("video").on("click", function(){
        if(this.paused)
            this.play();
        else
            this.pause();
    });
    
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var videoContainer = $(".video-container");
        
        for(var i = 0; i < videoContainer.length; i++)
        {
            timeChange($(videoContainer).children(".video"), "timeupdate", null);
        }
    });
    
    $(".full-screen").on("click", function(){
        var video = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        setFullScreenMode(video);
    });
    
    $(".big-icon").on("click", function(){
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        PlayPauseVideo(parent, "play");
    });
    
    $(".reproduction-body").on("mousedown", function(e){
        var repBody = this;
        e.preventDefault();
        moveSliderX(e, repBody);
        
        $("html").on("mousemove", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            moveSliderX(e, repBody);
        }).on("mouseup", function(){
            $(this).off("mousemove");
        });
    });
    
    $(".reproduction-body").on("mousemove", function(e){
        var repBody = this;
        e.preventDefault();
        moveTimeGlobeX(e, repBody);
        
    }).on("mouseout", function(){
        $(this).children(".time-globe").hide();
    });
    
    $(".volume-body").on("mousedown", function(e){
        var volBody = this;
        e.preventDefault();
        moveSliderY(e, volBody);
        
        $("html").on("mousemove", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            moveSliderY(e, volBody);
        }).on("mouseup", function(){
            $(this).off("mousemove");
        });
    });
    
    $(".volume-body").on("mousemove", function(e){
        var volBody = this;
        e.preventDefault();
        moveTimeGlobeY(e, volBody);
        
    }).on("mouseout", function(){
        $(this).children(".time-globe").hide();
    });
    
    $(".play, .pause").on("click", function(){
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        
        if($(this).hasClass("play"))
            PlayPauseVideo(parent, "play");
        else
            PlayPauseVideo(parent, "pause");
    });
    
    $(".icon-clickeable").on("click", function(){
        var elementParent = $(this).parent().parent().children(".element-parent");
        
        for(var i = 0; i < elementParent.length; i++)
        {
            var elementHidden = $(elementParent[i]).children(".element-hidden");
            
            if($(this).parent().attr("class") != $(elementParent[i]).attr("class"))
            {
                if($(elementHidden).css("display") != "none")
                    $(elementHidden).hide();
            }               
        }
        
        $(this).parent().children(".element-hidden").slideToggle();
    });
    
    $(".settings .setting-option").on("click", function(){
        var value = $(this).children().val();
        
        if(value != 0.5 && value != 1 && value != 1.5 && value != 2)
            $($(this).parent().children()[1]).click();
        else
        {
            $(this).parent().children(".active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().children("video").get(0).playbackRate = value; 
        }
    });
});

function moveSliderX(e, element)
{
    var pos = $(element).offset();
    var posX = e.pageX - pos.left;
    var parentVideo = $(element).parent().parent().parent();
    var video = $(parentVideo).children("video");   
    
    if(posX >= 0 && posX <= $(element).outerWidth())
    {
        timeChange(parentVideo, "moveslider", posX + "px");
        
        var duration = $(parentVideo).children("video").get(0).duration;
        var barSize = $(element).width();
        var repBarSize = $(element).children(".reproduction-played").width();

        var currentTime = (repBarSize * duration) / barSize;
        $(parentVideo).children("video").get(0).currentTime = currentTime;
    }

    if($(video).get(0).currentTime != $(video).get(0).duration)
    {
        $(parentVideo).children(".big-icon").hide();
    }   
}

function moveSliderY(e, element)
{
    var pos = $(element).offset();
    var posY = (pos.top + $(element).height()) - e.pageY;
    var parentVideo = $(element).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
    
    if(posY >= 0 && posY <= $(element).outerHeight())
    {
        $(element).children(".volume-actual").css("height", posY + "px");
        $(element).children(".circle-indicator").css("bottom", posY + "px");
        
        var altura = $(element).height();
        var volActual = posY / altura;
        
        var iconVol = $(element).parent().parent().children("i");
        
        if(volActual > 0.5)
            $(iconVol).attr("class", "fa fa-volume-up icon-clickeable");
        else if(volActual <= 0.5)
            $(iconVol).attr("class", "fa fa-volume-down icon-clickeable");
        else if(volActual == 0)
            $(iconVol).attr("class", "fa fa-volume-off icon-clickeable");
    
        $(parentVideo).children("video").get(0).volume = volActual;
    }
}

function moveTimeGlobeX(e, element)
{
    var pos = $(element).offset();
    var posX = e.pageX - pos.left;
    var parentVideo = $(element).parent().parent().parent();
    var video = $(parentVideo).children("video");   
    
    if(posX >= 0 && posX <= $(element).outerWidth())
    {
        var duration = $(parentVideo).children("video").get(0).duration;
        var barSize = $(element).width();

        var currentTime = (posX * duration) / barSize;
        
        $(element).children(".time-globe").css("left", posX + "px");
        $(element).children(".time-globe").children().text(segundosMinutos(currentTime));
        $(element).children(".time-globe").show();
    }
}

function moveTimeGlobeY(e, element)
{
    var pos = $(element).offset();
    var posY = (pos.top + $(element).height()) - e.pageY;
    var parentVideo = $(element).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
    
    if(posY >= 0 && posY <= $(element).outerHeight())
    {
        var altura = $(element).height();
        var volActual = Math.round(((posY / altura) * 100)) + "%";
        
        $(element).children(".time-globe").css("bottom", posY + "px");
        $(element).children(".time-globe").children().text(volActual);
        $(element).children(".time-globe").show();
    }
}

function setFullScreenMode(video)
{   
    var fullScreen = $(video).get(0);
    
    if($(fullScreen).hasClass("video-fullScreen"))
    {
        if(document.exitFullscreen)
            document.exitFullscreen();
        else if(document.webkitExitFullscreen)
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen)
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        else if(document.msExitFullscreen)
            document.msExitFullscreen();
    }
    else
    {
        if(fullScreen.requestFullscreen)
            fullScreen.requestFullscreen();
        else if(fullScreen.mozRequestFullScreen)
            fullScreen.mozRequestFullScreen();
        else if(fullScreen.webkitRequestFullScreen)
            fullScreen.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        else if(fullScreen.msRequestFullscreen)
            fullScreen.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
}

function eventFullScreen()
{
    if(CurrentlyInFullScreen())
    {
        var elementoActual = CurrentlyInFullScreen();
        $(elementoActual).addClass("video-fullScreen");
        $(elementoActual).children(".video-controlls").children(".video-options").children(".full-screen").children().attr("class", "fa fa-compress");
        timeChange(elementoActual, "timeupdate", null);
    }
    else
    {
        var elementoActual = $(".video-fullScreen");
        $(elementoActual).children(".video-controlls").children(".video-options").children(".full-screen").children().attr("class", "fa fa-expand");
        timeChange(elementoActual, "timeupdate", null);
        $(elementoActual).removeClass("video-fullScreen");
    }
}

function CurrentlyInFullScreen()
{
    return (document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement);
}

function timeChange(videoParent, type, actualWidth)
{
    var repCont = $(videoParent).children(".video-controlls").children(".reproduction-container");
    
    if(type == "timeupdate")
    {
        var width = $(repCont).children(".reproduction-body").width();
        var currentTime = $(videoParent).children("video").get(0).currentTime;
        var duration = $(videoParent).children("video").get(0).duration;
        var actualWidth = ((width * currentTime) / duration) + "px";
    }
    
    $(repCont).children(".reproduction-body").children(".reproduction-played").css("width", actualWidth);
    $(repCont).children(".reproduction-body").children(".circle-indicator").css("left", actualWidth);
}

function PlayPauseVideo(parent, type)
{
    if(type == "play")
    {
        if($(parent).children("video").get(0).readyState == 4)
            $(parent).children("video").get(0).play();          
    }
    else
        $(parent).children("video").get(0).pause();
}

function segundosMinutos(duracion)
{
    var segundos = duracion;
    var minutos = Math.floor(segundos / 60);
    var seg = Math.round(segundos % 60);
    
    if(minutos < 10)
        minutos = "0" + minutos;
    
    if(seg < 10)
        seg = "0" + seg;
    
    if(seg == 60)
    {
        minutos = parseInt(minutos) + 1;
        minutos = "0" + minutos;
        seg = "00";
    }
    
    var duracionTotal = minutos + ":" + seg;
    return duracionTotal;
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

i{
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Pantalla Completa */

::-webkit-media-controls{
    display: none!important;
}

::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure{
    display: none!important;
}

video:-webkit-full-screen{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.video-fullScreen{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* /Pantalla Completa */

.video-container{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.video-container .video{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}

.video-container .video video{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.video-fullScreen video{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.video-container .video .video-controlls{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 3px;
    display: none;
}

.video-fullScreen .video-controlls{
    padding: 17px;
}

/* Medidas del Reproductor */

.video-container .video .video-controlls .play-pause{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 7%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.video-container .video .video-controlls .time{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
}

.video-container .video .video-controlls .reproduction-container{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 65%;
    float: left;
}

.video-container .video .video-controlls .video-options{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13%;
    float: left;
}

/* /Medidas del Reproductor */

.video-container .video .video-controlls .play-pause .pause{
    display: none;
}

/* Tiempo de Reprudcción */

.video-container .video .video-controlls .reproduction-container .reproduction-body{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.video-container .video .video-controlls .reproduction-container .reproduction-body .time-globe{
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 4px;
    display: none;
}

.video-container .video .video-controlls .reproduction-container .reproduction-body .reproduction-played{
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #BB0101;
    width: 0;
}

.video-container .video .video-controlls .reproduction-container .reproduction-body .circle-indicator{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: -6px;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #BB0101;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #BB0101;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* /Tiempo de Reprudcción */

/* Volumen */

.video-container .video .video-controlls .video-options .volume{
    position: relative;
}

.video-container .video .video-controlls .video-options .volume .volume-container{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}

.video-container .video .video-controlls .video-options .volume .volume-container .volume-body{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #848484;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.video-container .video .video-controlls .video-options .volume .volume-container .volume-body .time-globe{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 15px;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 4px;
    display: none;
}

.video-container .video .video-controlls .video-options .volume .volume-container .volume-body .volume-actual{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 4px;
}

.video-container .video .video-controlls .video-options .volume .volume-container .volume-body .circle-indicator{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* /Volumen */

/* Configuración */

.video-container .video .video-controlls .video-options .volume,
.video-container .video .video-controlls .video-options .settings,
.video-container .video .video-controlls .video-options .full-screen{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.video-container .video .video-controlls .video-options .settings .settings-container{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 100px;
    display: none;
}

.video-container .video .video-controlls .video-options .settings .settings-container .setting-option{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.video-container .video .video-controlls .video-options .settings .settings-container .setting-option:hover,
.video-container .video .video-controlls .video-options .settings .settings-container .setting-option:active,
.video-container .video .video-controlls .video-options .settings .settings-container .setting-option.active{
    background-color: rgba(213, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.video-container .video .video-controlls .video-options .settings .settings-container .setting-option input{
    float: left;
}

/* /Configuración */

/* Big Icon */

.video-container .video .big-icon{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.video-container .video .big-icon .center-parent{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #FFF;
}

.video-container .video .big-icon .center-parent .center-children{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.video-container .video .big-icon .center-parent .center-children .icon-container-parent{
    margin: auto;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.video-container .video .big-icon .center-parent .center-children .icon-container-parent .icon-container-children{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 30px;
}

/* /Big Icon */
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="video">
        <video src="video.mp4" preload="metadata"></video>
        <div class="big-icon">
            <div class="center-parent">
                <div class="center-children">
                    <div class="icon-container-parent">
                        <div class="icon-container-children">
                            <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="video-controlls">
            <div class="play-pause">
                <div class="play">
                    <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="pause">
                    <i class="fa fa-pause"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="time">
                <span>
                    <span class="currentTime">00:00</span>/<span class="duration">00:00</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="reproduction-container">
                <div class="reproduction-body">
                    <div class="time-globe">
                        <span>00:00</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="reproduction-played">
                    </div>
                    <div class="circle-indicator">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="video-options">
                <div class="volume element-parent">
                    <i class="fa fa-volume-up icon-clickeable"></i>
                    <div class="volume-container element-hidden">
                        <div class="volume-body">
                            <div class="time-globe">
                                <span>00:00</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="volume-actual">
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-indicator">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="settings element-parent">
                    <i class="fa fa-cogs icon-clickeable"></i>
                    <div class="settings-container element-hidden">
                        <label class="setting-option">
                            <input type="radio" name="velocity" value="0.5">0.5
                        </label>
                        <label class="setting-option active">
                            <input type="radio" name="velocity" value="1" checked>Normal
                        </label>
                        <label class="setting-option">
                            <input type="radio" name="velocity" value="1.5">1.5
                        </label>
                        <label class="setting-option">
                            <input type="radio" name="velocity" value="2">2
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="full-screen">
                    <i class="fa fa-expand"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

El código que pongo del tutorial funciona perfectamente bien pero viene el detalle de que usan el selector universal `*` para aplicar ciertos estilos css a todos los elementos de la pagina incluyendo el reproductor y lo que quiero es aplicar ese selector unicamente a los elementos del reproductor, lo cual la aplicación del selector universal la modifique asi:

```
.video-container *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Como pueden ver cambie la aplicación del selector universal de manera que ahora los estilos de ese selector se apliquen a los elementos hijos del elemento que tiene la clase `.video-container` ya que este elemento es el contiene todo el reproductor, no se si también incluye al reproductor en el estado pantalla completa.

El problema aquí es que cuando el selector universal lo aplico a los elementos hijos del elemento que tiene la clase `.video-container` no funciona bien la barra que marca el tiempo de la reproducción del video ya que el circulo no se mueve correctamente.

Por ejemplo aplicando el selector universal a todos los elementos de la pagina, el circulo que marca el tiempo de la reproducción se mueve en el segundo 2 y si unicamente aplicamos el selector universal a los elementos del reproductor el circulo se mueve muchos segundos despues y no en el segundo 2 como sucede en el otro caso.

Es decir el movimiento del circulo en los dos casos no es el mismo.

Para que puedan ver el problema que les digo utilicen una pelicula o un video que tenga una duracion larga ya que si usan un video corto no se va anotar la diferencia que les comento.

Se que tal vez me podrán decir que use el plugin `videojs` pero no quiero usarlo porque el tiempo de la reproducción lo va marcando en negativo y quiero que ese tiempo lo marque en positivo, he estado buscando como cambiar esa situación en el plugin pero no he podido encontrar como hacerlo.

Comment: Hmmm mira, en este caso la pregunta es muy muy amplia, muchas veces nosotros queremos que el usuario nos deje algun codigo con el cual podemos darnos una idea de el porque no funciona o cual es el problema, en tu caso el problema queda claro, sin embargo temo decirte que no es directamente reproducible el problema aqui en `stackoverflow`, ten en cuenta que nosostros nada mas ejecutar tu snippet no podremos modificarlo para probar videos que nosotros tengamos en el sistema, pues como tal las rutas locales no serviran ya que el codigo esta en un servidor.

Comment: Sin embargo, si no estoy mal basta con que el elemento padre `.video-container` contenga esas reglas, no necesitas ponerle `.video-container *` ya que se supone los hijos heredan las propiedades del padre, aunque pues... por seguridad si seria bueno ponerlo, sin embargo, yo siempre te aconsejo usar ese selector universal tal cual lo usas en un principio, pues esas reglas en su mayoria son las que actualmente se ponen en una pagina web como estilos generales, son casi estandar.

Comment: Posdata, puede que nosotros podamos ayudarte, pero entonces deberas buscar un video en la red que no posea `CORS`, que sea un formato aceptado por el elemento `video` y que ademas sea largo, yo por ejemplo encontre este de aqui: https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/018/948/original/ICON-VERSION8_1.mp4 sin embargo el problema es que como es un video corto pasa lo que tu dices, no se puede apreciar ni la diferencia ni el problema.

Comment: Por cierto, pude ver un error que ocurre si no  le pones dimensiones lo suficientemente grandes a tu video, los elementos se superponen.